# Show that $\Bbb Q$ is zero-dimensional.

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

> Show that $\Bbb Q$ is zero-dimensional.

I’m not sure if I’m confusing something, but since $\Bbb Q$ is countable the set $\mathcal{B}=\{\{q\} : q \in \Bbb Q\}$ forms a basis for it? And by definiton a set is zero-dimensional if it has a basis whose elements are closed. So wouldn’t this imply that $\Bbb Q$ is of dimension zero?

Comment: No, the rationals are not discrete.

Comment: The Krull dimension of every field is zero. What dimension do you mean? The Hausdorff dimension of any countable set is zero.

Answer (score 8):

No, $\mathcal B$ is not a basis of the usual topology of $\Bbb Q$. Actually, *no* element of $\mathcal B$ is an open set with respect to that topology.

Instead, take $\mathcal B=\left\{(x,y)\cap\Bbb Q\,\middle|\,x,y\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\wedge x<y\right\}$. Then $\mathcal B$ *is* a basis of the usual topology of $\Bbb Q$. Furthermore, it consists of clopen sets, and therefore $\Bbb Q$ is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: To further explain why $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}$, any open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ can be written as a union of a sequence of open intervals where two end points are irrational.