# Prove that the set $\Bbb Q$ is of zero dimension when equipped with the standard topology.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Prove that the set $\Bbb Q$ is of zero dimension when equipped with the standard topology.

If I consider the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{(a,b) \cap \Bbb Q \mid a,b \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q \}$ so the set of all intervals $(a,b)$ with only rational numbers. I have that $\Bbb Q \subseteq \bigcup_{a,b \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q} (a,b) \cap \Bbb Q$ and if I take $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B} $, then $B_1 = (c,d) \cap \Bbb Q$ and $B_2 = (e,f) \cap \Bbb Q$. Assuming that $c<e<d<f
$. If $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$, then $x \in ((c,d) \cap \Bbb Q) \cap ((e,f) \cap \Bbb Q)) = (e,d) \cap \Bbb Q$ which is equal to some element $B$ in our collection So $\mathcal{B}$ forms a basis for $\Bbb Q$.

Now we need to show that the elements of our basis are closed.

Take some $B \in \mathcal{B}.$ Now $B = (a,b) \cap \Bbb Q$ for some $a,b \in \Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$. By definition $B$ is open in $\Bbb Q$ since it’s an element of the basis. Now the complement of $B$ is $B^c= \Bbb Q \setminus (a,b) \cap \Bbb Q = \Bbb Q \cap ((a,b) \cap \Bbb Q)^c$, but $(a,b) \cap \Bbb Q)^c $ is closed since it’s the complement of open set and by the subspace topology $\Bbb Q \cap ((a,b) \cap \Bbb Q)^c $ is closed in $\Bbb Q$.

Is the reasoning here correct? I’m unsure about the last part showing that the set is closed.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4241545/show-that-bbb-q-is-zero-dimensional) for a short answer.